# zend framework auth data with uploadify

Tags: zend-framework, uploadify

I have an issue with uploadify in zend framework.

Here is the upload url

```
'script'    : '/index/upload',
```

In this action I am unable to get auth data, which set at the time of login.

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$auth->getIdentity();
```

But when I access the upload action directly in the Browser then I can access the auth data.
The conclusion is not getting auth data in upload action while uploading with uploadify.

Comment: here is the uploading code
   $('#file_upload').uploadify({
      'uploader'  : '<?=$this->baseUrl?>/public/www/js/uploader/uploadify.swf',
      'script'    : '<?=$this->baseUrl?>/index/upload',
      'cancelImg' : '<?=$this->baseUrl?>/public/www/images/uploader/cancel.png',
      'fileExt'     : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
      'folder'    : '/public/uploads',
      'fileDesc'    : 'Image Files',
      'auto'      : true,
       });

Comment: I want to access auth data in upload action while uploading.

Comment: and directly means access url manualy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sessions and uploadify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284666/sessions-and-uploadify)

Comment: This probably is actually known, check the second answer in the duplicate link.

Comment: are you testing this on localhost ?? since your url is relative which might not work correctly if no virtualhost has been created or baseUrl view helper is used to create the url .